# importing an exported value from another js file throws unexpected identifier, how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There are two js files in my working directory.

Here is the content of `test.js`

```
let k; export default k = 12;
```

Here is the content of `test2.js`

```
import m from './test';
console.log(m);
```

When I tried to run `test2.js` with node.js (v17.3.0)

```
node test2.js
```

I got

```
import m from './test';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

The example code comes from [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export)

Am I using export correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You're using ESM syntax, but the CommonJS loader. You need to put `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` file to tell Node.js that you're using ESM (or use a `.mjs` file extension). Details [in the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).
2. You've said you're exporting the variable, but you aren't; you're exporting a constant value (`12`, the result of `k = 12`) as the default export. To export the variable as the default export, you'd use:

   ```
   let k = 12;
   export default k;
   ```

   The distinction is that if you export the result of `k = 12` instead of `k`, later assignments to `k` within the exporting module won't update the imported binding's value.

---

Side note: Default exports are generally not a great idea. Instead, consider using a *named* export:

```
// Exporting:
export let k = 12;
// Importing:
import {k as m} from "./test.js";
console.log(m); // 12 (initially, will change if `k` is changed)
```

Comment: (FWIW, I go into `import`/`export` syntax in some detail [including how to use them in Node.js] in Chapter 13 of my recent book, *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links and such in my profile if you're interested.)